# wp-load.php adding some empty char that stocks my JSON

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create json page so other servers will be able to get my info.
In the head of my php file I include the wp-load.php file because I use some wordpress function in the code. 
The problem is that this file add a empty char ->""  in the file and now the syntax for the json is wrong. ("JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate")
 What can I do?

JSON:

```
{"liked":"#Msg11456622,#Msg11456702,#Msg11456709","followed":"0","forumFavorite":"0","forumFollowed":"0","myAdmin":"0"}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
?>{"liked":"#Msg11456622,#Msg11456702,#Msg11456709","followed":"0","forumFavorite":"0","forumFollowed":"0","myAdmin":"0"}
```

Comment: Please post the code, not just the json.

Comment: added, but the problem is the syntax of the json was created. I check with outside validator.

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way.  Totally the wrong way.  Write an actual [WordPress plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), use [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to hook into the [wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) or [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hooks, render the json, then `die()`.  Something like what [this article](https://webdevstudios.com/2015/07/09/creating-simple-json-endpoint-wordpress/) covers would work.